# Shortcut to swtich windows of a current application does not work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xorg, wayland, 23.10

Usually, I use the following keyboard shortcuts to move around windows:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch through windows from **all** applications,
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch through applications,
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> or
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to switch through windows from the **current** application.

The last two (to switch through windows from the **current** application) do not work anymore. I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 and x11 (not Wayland).

I've read many related questions on this forum but didn't find any solution that works for me.

Note I'm using an AZERTY keyboard so key <kbd>`</kbd> is actually <kbd>²</kbd> in my case.

EDIT: Surprisingly, it is working just fine now.

EDIT2: Not working anymore.

Comment: Having the same problem, also in X11. It seems to come and go, so any anwser to this is still valuable.